# AS: getting XML attribute of selected row in AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: xml, actionscript, advanceddatagrid

I populate an AdvancedDataGrid with XML Data, this is an example of the XML data I use :

```
<list>
  <root>
    <item text="Folder" id="1" isBranch="true" classes="folder">
      <item text="SubFolder" id="2" isBranch="true" classes="folder">
        <item text="Item" id="3" isBranch="false" classes="item" col1="1" col2="2" />
      </item>
      <item text="Folder" id="4" isBranch="true" classes="folder">
        <item text="Item" id="5" isBranch="false" classes="item" col1="3" col2="4"/>
      </item>
    </item>
  </root>
</list>
```

After the user then clicks on a cell, I would like to retrieve the attributes of the node he clicked on.

So, for example, if the user clicks on column 1 of the Item with ID 3, I need to access the attributes of this XML node :

```
<item text="Item" id="3" isBranch="false" classes="item" col1="1" col2="2" />
```

So I can find out the ID of this item (in this case 3).

Note that this ID is never displayed in the AdvancedDataGrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you want but here it goes.

```
<controls:AdvancedDataGrid dataProvider="{ new HierarchicalData(list) }"
                           itemClick="{ idLabel.text = event.itemRenderer.data.@id }">

    <controls:columns>
        <!-- some sample columns -->
        <advanceddatagridclasses:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="@text"/>
        <advanceddatagridclasses:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="@isBranch"/>
        <advanceddatagridclasses:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="@col1"/>
        <advanceddatagridclasses:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="@col2"/>
    </controls:columns>

</controls:AdvancedDataGrid>

<s:Label id="idLabel" />
```

The important thing to retain is this line:

```
event.itemRenderer.data.@id
```

Whenever you click on a AdvancedDataGrid item, the "itemClick" event will be dispatched. This event contains a reference to the *itemRenderer* which by its turn contains a reference to the *data* being displayed on that row. In this case, to access the *id* attribute you just need to use `data.@id`.

If you want, you can have something like this:

```
<controls:AdvancedDataGrid dataProvider="{ new HierarchicalData(list) }"
                           itemClick="{ doSomething(event.itemRenderer.data) }">
```

and then create a `doSomething` method which will receive the "clicked" XML node as param.

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, didn't realise it was that simple .. thanks mate !

Comment: but how to group them by attribute? let's say by folder?